# AWS SQS - boto3 HTTPClientError - tuple index out of range

Tags: boto3, botocore

Intermittently seeing this error when enqueuing SQS messages with boto. The same operation succeeds upon retry.
This is with boto==1.21.28, botocore==1.24.28

Is it possible this could be a bug in botocore?

```
[ERROR] HTTPClientError: An HTTP Client raised an unhandled exception: tuple index out of range
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/foo/bar/baz/queue.py", line 47, in enqueue_foo
    sqs.Queue(SOME_QUEUE).send_message(
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 520, in do_action
    response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)
  <--snipped to placate stackoverflow formatter-->
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 317, in _send
    return self.http_session.send(request)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/botocore/httpsession.py", line 448, in send
    raise HTTPClientError(error=e)
```

Comment: Can you post what you were trying to send?

Comment: @Andy Did you figure out what happened? Having similar issue with boto + sagemaker-client